# 'is'/'is not' behaviour in python

Tags: python

Why do these not yield the same result:

```
None is not None is False
>>False

(None is not None) is False
>>True
```

I was expecting python to interpret the first line just like second. Why doesn't it?

Using python 3.7.

Comment: Because [comparison operators chain](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) in Python.

Comment: For the same reason why expressions like `0 < x < 10` work, which is interpreted as `(0 < x) and (x < 10)`. Your first line is interpreted as `(None is not None) and (None is False)`.

Comment: With the possible exception of the mathematical operators, I think this is really unintuitive and the potential costs far outweigh the minimal benefit. Writing code like `if a != b in mylist`, for example, isn't helpful in any meaningful way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the reason is that all comparison operators in python chain.
Thanks to @khelwood and @Paul M.

```
None is not None is False
```

is the same as

```
(None is not None) and (None is False)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence, you can see that the 'not' operator is executed later than the 'is' operator.

Edit: this is **False**. @khelwood is correct: it is due to expression chaining https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons (same page, different section)

Comment: This isn't quite the case: `is` and `is not` have the same precedence according to that table

Comment: @sacuL you're right, I was a bit too quick reading the table and stopped at the first 'not' I found